# Pass template class instance type alias to non-member template function

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to pass template class instances type alias (`ClassTmplt/DerivedFloat::InternalType`) to external non-member template function (`DoSomething`) using `Base` class object pointer (like in two last `test()` function commented lines)?

```
class Base
{
};

template <typename T>
class ClassTmplt:
    public Base
{
public:
    using InternalType = T;
};

class DerivedFloat:
    public ClassTmplt<float>
{
};

template <typename T, typename TIn>
void DoSomething(const TIn value)
{
    T val = T(value);
    std::cout << val << " | " << typeid(val).name() << " | " << typeid(value).name() << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
typename T::InternalType PassInternalType(T* obj)
{
    return T::InternalType;
    //return obj::InternalType
}


void test()
{
    Base* obj = new DerivedFloat;
    DoSomething<float>(1.23);
    DoSomething<DerivedFloat::InternalType>(1UL);
    //DoSomething<(*obj)::InternalType>(-123);
    //DoSomething<PassInternalType(obj)>(4.56);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Consider:

```
void f(Base* ptr) {
    // What type does ptr point to?
    // The runtime derived type might not exist when this function compiles
}
```

Since the dynamic type of the pointer is only know at runtime, it's impossible for the compiler to gain access to it when compiling the function.

If the definition is available there may be some more options, but all of them require you knowing in advance the entire set of types you intend to support, and possibly need to downcast to first.  (A type "id" might help if you go this route.)

You might be able to build some limited working designs with a visitor pattern.

Comment: Thanks. What you mean by downcasting - something other than ID-field in Base class containing unique ID's for each class in hierarchy? I have such field, but as I can't make it constexpr I have failed to make a templates specialized by this ID-field to use in DoSomething...

Comment: I mean, if a derived class exposes a type, you cannot access it if you only know the base type.  That's frequently why people use the CRTP - Curiously Recurring Template Pattern.  A base is template, and parameter is the derived class type passing itself up so base can use it.

Comment: Argh... Why I haven't though about template base class :| Thank you very much for CPTR.